# Using the linux play command, how can I set the volume during playback?

Tags: shell, linux-mint

The cli command `play 'some audio file.mp3'` is working, but I'd like to adjust the volume by about half for that particular playback.

How can I accomplish this with the `play` command?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the volume to be perceived as about half of full volume, I had to do:

`play --volume 0.2 'some audio file.mp3'`